# 579-579/? E/StreamVibrator: Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating

Tags: android

The wear emulator shows me that error when I'm trying to get a notification on wear.

It gives me the following error:

> 579-579/? E/StreamVibrator: Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating.

```
Notification notification= new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle("new message received")
                .setContentText(bundle.getString("MESSAGE"))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).build();
```